# Unable to pass parameters to wired property in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

Unable to pass parameters to wired property in LWC.

I have a standalone `app`

```html
    <aura:application  extends="force.slds">
        <c:abc a="a" b="a,b,c" c="c" />
    </aura:application>
```

and Lightning Web Component `abc`.

Listing of `abc.html`

```html
    <template>
        {d}  {e} 
        <template if:true={deWired}>
            Data: {deWired.data}
            Error:  {deWired.error}
        </template> 
    </template>
```

Listing of `abc.js`

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
    import getDE from '@salesforce/apex/ABCCont.getDE';
    export default class Abc extends LightningElement {
        @api a;
        @api b;
        @api c;
    
        @wire(getDE, { a:this.a, b:this.b.split(','), c:this.c})
        deWired = {};
    
        @track d;
        @track e;
        @track error;
        connectedCallback() {
            getDE({ a:this.a, b:this.b.split(','),c:this.c}).then(result=>{
                    this.d = result.d;
                    this.e = result.e;
                }).catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                });
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use wired property `deWired` and wire it to the method which requires three parameters which I want to pass from another app or component which references this component. However, when I try to do this, I receive an error

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Failed to initialize a component [Cannot read property 'a' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:App}
```

[image]

When I comment out lines

```js
    @wire(getDE, { a:this.a, b:this.b.split(','), c:this.c})
    deWired = {};
```

it works like a charm. So looks like the problem is with wired property. Is there any way to use a wired property here? Are we obliged to use only Imperative Apex in this case?

Apex controller is irrelevant here, but just for reference listing of dummy ABCCont

```java
    public inherited sharing class ABCCont {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static Map<String, Object> getDE(String a, List<String> b, String c) {
            return new Map<String, Object>{'d'=>'d','e'=>'e'};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you commit suicide after having used LWC? Having to develop without a stacktrace. Seriously, I'm ready to jump out of the window.

Comment: @Trace, hah, not yet, I am still alive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) you want to mark your @wire methods differently.

Also from the doc:

> In the wire adapter’s configuration object, prefix a value with $ to
>   reference a property of the component instance. The $ prefix tells the
>   wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as
>   this.propertyName. The property is reactive. If the property’s value
>   changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders.

The right syntax is:

```
 @wire(getDE, { a: '$a', b: '$b', c: '$c' })
    deWired;
```

You also shouldn't need to call it in your `connectedCallback`. You can also edit your `deWrired` syntax to perform callback actions

```
@wire(getDE, { a: '$a', b: '$b', c: '$c' })
    deWired({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.d = data.d;
            this.e = data.e;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```